Does anyone know the anime movie where a guy has to save the world?
So what I remember is:

This movie was shown on Adult Swim about 3 times
It starts with 2 guys playing a game on a computer in the same room. The game is like Sim City. The guys work at a very popular electronics place, like Apple.
A girl walks in and asks if one of the 2 guys can go with her to see her family. When they get there, she introduces him as her husband. At first the guy tries to deny it, but the girl asks him to play along.
Towards the end, he has to save the world with the company he was pretending to work on in the Sim City game.

That's all I can remember. Do any of you know what anime movie this is?

The movie you're looking for is the excellent Summer Wars, released in 2009.


It starts with 2 guys playing a game on a computer in the same room. The game is like Sim City.

The plot of Summer Wars centres around OZ, an online virtual world in which people control 3D avatars. It's more than just a "game": it features areas for online shopping and all sorts. 

The guys work at a very popular electronics place, like Apple.

The two students, Kenji and Takashi, are part-time moderators within OZ.

A girl walks in and asks if one of the 2 guys can go with her to see her family. When they get there, she introduces him as her husband. At first the guy tries to deny it, but the girl asks him to play along.

Kenji is invited by his classmate Natsuki to a family reunion, to celebrate the 90th birthday of Natsuki's great-grandmother. Once there, Natsuki introduces Kenji as her fiancé, and asks him to play along.

Towards the end, he has to save the world

The main plot revolves around the malicious AI "Love Machine", which hijacks Kenji's OZ account and uses it to cause widespread chaos within the virtual world (and eventually, the real world as well). At the film's climax, Love Machine hijacks a satellite and sends it on a collision course with Earth, first aiming for a nuclear power plant, then for the family's house. Kenji hacks the satellite's GPS and manages to divert it away just in time.
